# Transforming Streaming XSLT Without a Custom Content Handler

Tags: java, xml, xslt, streaming, saxon

Take a look at this website:

http://xmpp.wordpress.com:8008/firehose.xml?type=text/plain

It constantly streams data.  You can transform this content using the newest version of XSLT (v3), with a command like this:

```
<xsl:stream href="http://xmpp.wordpress.com:8008/firehose.xml?type=text/plain">
```

If I want to write some Java code to initiate the transformation (using Saxon, which has implemented xsl:stream), I can do this:

```
// XSL
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(xslFile)));
// XML
StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(xmlFile));
// Output
MyCustomContentHandler handler = new MyCustomContentHandler();  
PrintStream outputPrintStream = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)), true);
handler.setPrintStream(outputPrintStream);
Result result = new SAXResult(handler);
// Transform
transformer.transform(xmlSource, result);
```

This works.  If you let it run for a bit, then open the output file, you’ll see data in it.  If you re-open it a bit later, you’ll see even more data.  The key to this is the custom content handler that processes the various SAX events.

But suppose that I don’t really want a custom content handler.  Suppose I just want to keep the output of the XSLT as is.  I can modify my code like this:

```
// XSL
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(xslFile)));
// XML
StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(xmlFile));
// Output
TransformerHandler transformerHandler = ((SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance()).newTransformerHandler();
transformerHandler.setResult(new StreamResult(new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true), true)));
// or this…
//transformerHandler.setResult(new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)));
// or this…
//transformerHandler.setResult(new StreamResult(new FileWriter(outputFile)));
ContentHandler contentHandler = (ContentHandler) transformerHandler;
SAXResult result = new SAXResult(transformerHandler);
// Transform
transformer.transform(xmlSource, result);
```

The good news is that I no longer need a custom content handler, and my output now matches the output of the XSLT exactly.  The bad news is that although this code works with non-streaming XSLT, it does not work with streaming XSLT.  Despite my various attempts at setting the result (see the “or this…” statements above), nothing is written to the file.  I suspect there’s a buffering problem of some sort.

Question:  How can I combine the best of these two together?  How can I transform a streaming XSLT without having to use a custom content handler?

Comment: I have not used that stuff but looking at your code the first version uses a `PrintStream` over a `BufferedOutputStream` while in the second version I see no `BufferedOutputStream`. Have you tried to use a `BufferedOutputStream` as well in the second version? What does your `MyCustomContentHandler` look like exactly that might be different?

Comment: Adding a `BufferedOutputStream` into the mix doesn't help, because it still needs a `FileOutputStream` to write the results into a file:  `transformerHandler.setResult(new StreamResult(new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output, true)), true)));`

Comment: I can paste the content of the custom handler, but I don't see how that's relevant.  1) For the most part, it's simply attempting to be the identity function.  2) I'm trying to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, it does not appear to be possible to do what I want to do.  My current solution is to use a custom content handler (per my question above) and run its results through a standard XSLT identity transformation.  A bit ugly and not very efficient, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a rerun of a thread on the saxon-help list in June:

http://sourceforge.net/p/saxon/mailman/message/32472658/

The conclusion there was that the output was somehow being buffered in the output stream pipeline. Saxon is emitting events representing the transformation result, as you see by supplying a ContentHandler, but the serialization of these events is being buffered in the I/O system.

Comment: Yes, it is, and I should have put a link back to your conversation with Roger.  That's what got me as far as I am, but unfortunately it doesn't answer the question I have now:  How can I get Saxon to support `<xslt:stream>` without using a custom content handler?  I can't get it to work.

Comment: I don't know what's going on, but I do know the problem isn't in Saxon, it's downstream. Saxon is sending stuff to the output stream continuously, it's then being buffered.